# GeoTools: grid transformation using NTv2Transform - error locating grid file

Tags: coordinate-system, geotools, jts-topology-suite

I'm trying to use GeoTools library to calculate the grid coverage based on NTv2 .gsb file.

However, I'm unable to create the instance of NTv2Transform.

When I use this piece of code:

```
File gridFile = new File("C:\\Dev\\VTS\\Grids\\WA\\wohpgn.gsb");
NTv2Transform transform = new NTv2Transform(gridFile.toURI());
```

I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchIdentifierException: Could not locate NTv2 Grid File file:/C:/Dev/VTS/Grids/WA/wohpgn.gsb
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.transform.NTv2Transform.<init>(NTv2Transform.java:105)
    at com.frequentis.example.Main.transformFromNad27UsingGrid(Main.java:75)
    at com.frequentis.example.Main.main(Main.java:90)
```

Am I using the syntax properly?
Is there some other way of how to achieve that?
Do you know about some workaround?

I was trying it with versions 18.4 and 19.1 with Maven.

Comment: Having the same Error with Ubuntu...

Comment: try using URLs.fileToUrl to make the conversion - it handles windows paths better

Comment: The file URI's root is in your `org.geotools.referencing.factory.gridshift` folder, so just using `new URI("wohpgn.gsb")` should be enough. I had to use the debugger in NTv2Transform, though, so it wasn't obvious.